# Saving log from the robocopy command to a dated log file

Tags: datetime, batch-file, logging, cmd, robocopy

I'm running the following command to backup a folder to a remote a share mapped as a drive:

```
REM Backup local documents to Q drive, only add new files does not remove old
REM files
echo --------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Running backup to Q batch, only adding new files
echo --------------------------------------------------------------------------
robocopy C:\WhatIWantToCopy^
    Q:\ /256 /V /S /IPG:125^
    /XF *.log /tee /ETA /XC /XN /XO^ 
    /XD C:\SomeRubbish^
    /log:C:\MyStuff\logs\robo_%_DATETIME.log
```

The command executes but the line:

```
/log:C:\MyStuff\logs\robo_%_DATETIME.log
```

does not appear to be generating the required log file. I would like for the log file to be of structure **robo_16-12-2015.log**, reflecting the current date.

Comment: variables are used with a percent sign at the front AND at the end: `%_datetime%` (assuming, it's defined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to construct the date in the format you want. This snip should help:

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO Date: %DATE%
ECHO Time: %TIME%

SET _datetime=%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~10,4%
ECHO %_datetime%
```

On my machine, this outputs:

```
Date: Wed 12/16/2015
Time: 14:42:08.21
16-12-2015
```

If you want to include an Hour-Minute timestamp, just update accordingly parsing the `%TIME%` variable:

```
SET _datetime=%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~10,4%_%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful input. For the sake of learning, where can I learn how to parse date/time in batch files?

Comment: @Konrad - `%DATE%` and `%TIME%` are built in variables. I am parsing them using the `SET` substring syntax which you can see here: `SET /?`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem as follows: my server returns this:

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO Date: %DATE%
ECHO Time: %TIME%

Date: Thu 06/29/2017
Time: 11:19:24.02
```

Now, I want to use a log file with Robocopy that has a "Year-Month-Day--Hour-Minute-Second" part in the file name. The challenge here is to get rid of the / and : characters, because these are not allowed in file names.

The solution: create a batch file, e.g. setdtvar.cmd, with this in it:

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO Date: %DATE%
ECHO Time: %TIME%

SET DTVARYEAR=%DATE:~10%
ECHO %DTVARYEAR%

SET DTVARDAY=%DATE:~7,2%
ECHO %DTVARDAY%

SET DTVARMONTH=%DATE:~4,2%
ECHO %DTVARMONTH%

SET DTVARTIMEHRS=%TIME:~0,2%
ECHO %DTVARTIMEHRS%

SET DTVARTIMEMIN=%TIME:~3,2%
ECHO %DTVARTIMEMIN%

SET DTVARTIMESEC=%TIME:~6,2%
ECHO %DTVARTIMESEC%

SET DTVAR=%DTVARYEAR%-%DTVARMONTH%-%DTVARDAY%--%DTVARTIMEHRS%-%DTVARTIMEMIN%-%DTVARTIMESEC%

ECHO %DTVAR%
```

On my server, the DTVAR variable now returns the date and time in the format I need, for example:

```
2017-06-29--11-19-24
```

To enable this function for Robocopy: Each batch file that contains robocopy commands first calls the setdtvar.cmd file (call setdtvar.cmd in the first line). This sets the DTVAR variable in the context of the process that runs the batch file. Then, in the Robocopy log file command, I use %DTVAR% in the filename of the log file.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question you can use the following code.  This code also support old systems the have a day listed in the `DATE` variable.

```vb
SET sDate=%DATE%
SET "sFirstChar=%sDate:~0,1%"
SET "sNum="&FOR /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%sFirstChar%") DO SET sNum=%%i
IF DEFINED sNum ( GOTO DateHasDay ) ELSE ( GOTO DateHasNoDay )
:DateHasDay
SET sDate=%sDate:~4%
SET sDate=%sDate:~3,2%-%sDate:~0,2%-%sDate:~-4,4%
GOTO DateSet
:DateHasNoDay
SET sDate=%sDate:~3,2%-%sDate:~0,2%-%sDate:~-4,4%
:DateSet
ECHO C:\MyStuff\logs\robo_%sDate%.log
```

Just to add a simpler approach that have served me well over the years and avoids name collisions.  Below is a snip-it that I have in my script file that I use as a robocopy migration script.  I use this to generate new log file names each time it's ran.  The name of this particular script I have is called "migrate.bat".  As you can see this code will use the name of the script and then spit out a nice log file name to use.

```vb
:: Generate date and time stamp for backups
SET sDateTime=%DATE%
SET "sFirstChar=%sDateTime:~0,1%"
SET "sNum="&FOR /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%sFirstChar%") DO SET sNum=%%i
IF DEFINED sNum ( GOTO DateHasDay ) ELSE ( GOTO DateHasNoDay )
:DateHasDay
SET sDateTime=%sDateTime:~4%
SET sDateTime=%sDateTime:~-4,4%%sDateTime:~0,2%%sDateTime:~3,2%
GOTO DateSet
:DateHasNoDay
SET sDateTime=%sDateTime:~-4,4%%sDateTime:~0,2%%sDateTime:~3,2%
:DateSet
SET sHr=%TIME:~0,2%
IF "%sHr:~0,1%"==" " SET sHr=0%sHr:~1,1%
SET sMin=%TIME:~3,2%
IF "%sMin:~0,1%"==" " SET sMin=0%sMin:~1,1%
SET sSec=%TIME:~6,2%
IF "%sSec:~0,1%"==" " SET sSec=0%sSec:~1,1%
SET sDateTime=%sDateTime%-%sHr%%sMin%%sSec%
SET sLogFileSuffix=-%sDateTime%.log
```

Then see what it looks like...

```vb
ECHO %~n0%sLogFileSuffix%
```

Should return something like...

> migrate-20181022-082516.log